# Mount cifs permission problem on deep directory perhaps due to UNC and prefixpath splitting

Tags: permissions, samba, cifs

I am trying to mount a directory (dir3).  However, on the windows machine the directory /server/dir1 is already a file shared folder, but I don't have permission to it.  I have been given the read permissions to //server/dir1/dir2/dir3.  An example of the command I am running and the response that I am getting are given below.

```
~# mount -vt cifs //server/dir1/dir2/dir3 /mount/directory -o credentials=/file/credentials
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=10.10.10.10,unc=\\server\dir2,credential=/file/credentials,ver=1,user=user,domain=sbts,prefixpath=dir2/dir3,pass=********
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

From my Mac I am able to use the same credentials to connect to `//server/dir1/dir2/dir3`, so I'm assuming there is something wrong with my "mount -t cifs" command and not my credentials.

My guess is that the mount command, in splitting the `//server/dir1/dir2/dir3` line into `unc=\\server\dir1` and `prefixpath=dir2/dir3`, is causing the transaction to try and test for permissions against `\\server\dir1` and not `//server/dir1/dir2/dir3`.

Is there any way to keep the `mount -t cifs` command from splitting `//server/dir1/dir2/dir3` into `unc=\\server\dir1` and `prefixpath=dir2/dir3`? Or this there some other way to fix my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. The given by me `DFS` was divided into 2 parts: `uns` and `prefixpath`.

The "break through" for me was to activate the diagnostic for the `cifs`:

```
$ echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/fs/cifs/cifsFYI
```

Then after another unsuccessful mount attempt I looked inside the dmesg-log

```
$ dmesg
```

and saw the cause of the mount-problem:

```
fs/cifs/cifs_dfs_ref.c: cifs_compose_mount_options: Failed to resolve server part of <HERE_WAS_UNC_PART_OF_MY_DFS> to IP: -11
```

"Googling" the error led me to the following 2 articles:

1. https://vlkan.com/blog/post/2015/01/08/smb-mount-troubleshoot/
2. https://access.redhat.com/solutions/45070

Short summary of these articles:

1. Instal the `keyutils` package
2. Append the following lines to the `/etc/request-key.conf`:

```
create cifs.spnego * * /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall -c %k
create dns_resolver * * /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall %k
```

Profit!